# Editing the mailbody of a workflow

Tags: sharepoint

i have a list in SharePoint site when user add a item in the list a mail will be send to the approval group and this is working fine

what i want is t o edit the body mail of that message so any one have a idea how to do that

Comment: Post your future questions here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this if you're using the out of the box (ootb) Approval workflows. The message bodies and subjects are templates held in resource DLLs, and are governed by language packs.

The only way you could do this is by setting up a custom SMTP proxy that transforms the emails on the way through before passing them to a real SMTP server for delivery. I don't have any example code for that, sorry.

-Oisin